# Starting fresh project using Sharepoint 2010 foundation

Tags: content-type

I have a wss 3.0 site that is working and functional. I didn't wanted to migrate the site to Sharepoint foundation as there are some issues with the site during migration.

Also I would like to have this site in Sharepoint foundation 2010 but want to follow best practices.

I have the following in wss 3.0 site

- Few sharepoint lists and document libraries.
- The list pages such as newform, editform, dispform were all customized using sharepoint designer in wss 3.0 site which I don't want to do in SP 2010. I would instead want to create pages for each one of them and use it.
- I used heavy javascript (for client side validation, display etc) in wss 3.0 but want to use the best possibile options in SP 2010.

Please suggest on the above,

To begin with I plan to create blank site. I would like to create all the lists/libraries through code as the site will be reused on different servers. Question here is some of the columns in these lists are common (such as employee ID, Dept). Is it better to create a content type and then site columns as employeeID, dept. Then in each of the lists, I can reference them? I am bit confused on this. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the option to start from scratch, and there's not that much content in terms of items, then great! If you have the opportunity to build a fresh information architecture with content types then even better.

Absolutely use Content Types and Site Columns from columns that get frequently used throughout your site collections.

You can create this from a Feature, which you create into a WSP Solution in Visual Studio to ease deployment of these across site collections.

Comment: thanks for the inputs. I plan to create content types & site columns once the site is created. I know that I need to write a feature upon site creation but I am looking for example of creating custom content type and site column using visual studio approach. Plus also the next feature would be create lists programatically.                  Please suggest.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231593.aspx - you can stop at "List Defintion" section

Comment: The MSDN example above is more imperative (or not C# based)? I am looking to do complete c# or feature driven approach. Any examples? thanks.

Comment: Yup, loads. Here's the MSDN example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798370.aspx And the word of note is "Programmatically" if you want to find other examples on Bingle.

Comment: That method added the field using XML, you can also use the Object Model, like here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/syedi/archive/2008/09/24/programmatically-creating-a-field-column-from-the-custom-field-type-in-wss-3-0-moss.aspx, again, just google for "sharepoint programmatically create fields".